# Where do piped files go on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, vim, vi

I was experimenting with pipelines in Git Bash. I ran "ls || vim", thinking that it would open Vim with the contents of the Directory Listing written into the editor. That is not the case, and rather, it saved the file. I haven't been able to find where, though. Any ideas?

Git Bash starts at /d/Desktop, and Git Bash is located at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git. Any locations this file might be would be helpful.

EDIT: Sorry, I ran "ls | vim". Also, output was:
"Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Error reading input, exiting...
Preserving Files...
Finished"

EDIT: Sorry for the off-topic post, and thank you for your answers. I'll check out SuperUser if I ever have any more similar questions.

Comment: What did it do, *exactly*, that gave you the impression that it "saved the file"?

Comment: To be clear -- `||` is a logical-OR, it's not a pipe. It means "do this; if it fails, then do that instead". So in your current case, it means "try to run `ls`, and if `ls` fails, then run `vim`". The presumptive occurrence is that `ls` *didn't* fail, so `vim` didn't run.

Comment: (BTW, general-purpose questions on how to use the shell, vs about software development, tend to be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/); StackOverflow's scope is explicitly limited to questions "unique to software development"; lots of folks who aren't software developers use bash).

Comment: Sorry, I may have posted this in the wrong place. I'm fairly new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls || vim
```

See `||` as OR. `vim` is never executed because `ls` is not `False`.

---

```
ls | vim
```

See `|` as pipe. But it will give:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

---

So use

```
ls | vim -
```

because vim will then read from standard-in.